# morgan won't load module 'debug' on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have this in my express settings

```
var morgan     = require("morgan");
app.use(morgan("dev"));
```

This works on my development macine, but crashes when I deploy to Heroku:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/morgan/index.js:16:13)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
app[web.1]: module.js:338
app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
app[web.1]:     throw err;
app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
app[web.1]:           ^
app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can replicate the problem by running node from the Heroku CLI, and trying to `require` morgan. Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
> var morgan     = require("morgan");
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/morgan/index.js:16:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Line 16 of index.js reads `var debug = require('debug')('morgan')`.

The debug module does lack an `index.js`, but has this in its `package.json` instead

```
  "main": "./node.js",
  "browser": "./browser.js",
  "component": {
    "scripts": {
      "debug/index.js": "browser.js",
      "debug/debug.js": "debug.js"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out was something to do with an out-of-date package and updating to latest enabled me to progress

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with this solution?  I'm having a similar problem and was wondering if you had any further information.

Comment: I've rather forgotten but it looks as though I had an old version of Morgan installed and updating fixed it